# Query AD group members and sort by Firstname, Lastname & UPN

Tags: powershell

How do I get use `Get-ADGroupMembers` cmdlet to query group members and sort by First name, Last name, UPN? I've been using the following codes but and both return null string.

Code 1:

```psh
Get-ADGroupMember "CN=guelphmail, OU=Lists,OU=UofGelph,DC=corp,DC=uofg,DC=com" |
  select firstname, lastname
```

Code 2:

```psh
$users = Get-ADGroupMember "CN=guelphmail, OU=Lists,OU=UofGelph,DC=corp,DC=uofg,DC=com"
$users |
  Select-Object @{n="First Name";e={$_.FirstName}},
                @{n="Last Name";e={$_.LastName}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects returned by [`Get-ADGroupMember`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617193.aspx) don't include the attributes you're looking for. You need to resolve them to user objects before you can select the users' first and last names and UPNs.

```psh
$dn = 'CN=guelphmail,OU=Lists,OU=UofGelph,DC=corp,DC=uofg,DC=com'
$properties = 'GivenName', 'Surname', 'UserPrincipalName'

Get-ADGroupMember $dn | Get-ADUser -Property $properties | select $properties
```

If you want to rename `GivenName` and `Surname` to `FirstName` and `LastName` respectively you need to use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
select @{n='FirstName';e={$_.GivenName}},
       @{n='LastName';e={$_.Surname}},
       UserPrincipalName
```

Comment: I received this error:  
Get-ADUser : One or more properties are invalid.
Parameter name: FirstName
At line:4 char:25
+ Get-ADGroupMember $dn | Get-ADUser -Property $properties | select $properties

Comment: @NebelzCheez Yeah, the names of the first and last name properties were wrong. See updated answer.

Comment: Same Error: Get-ADUser : One or more properties are invalid.
Parameter name: FirstName
At line:6 char:25
+ Get-ADGroupMember $dn | Get-ADUser -Property $properties | select $properties
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: @NebelzCheez Take a closer look at how `$properties` is defined in my updated answer. Do you see a `FirstName` in there?